# BlackBerry 9860 simulator wrong resolution

Tags: cordova, blackberry, blackberry-simulator

I'm currently trying to test my phonegap app thru the BlackBerry 9860 simulator but have alot of problem.

So I decide to output the width/height with javascript (window.innerWidth & window.innerHeight) and surprise, I got 288x480.

If I look at BlackBerry 9860 spec, it's supposed to be 480x800 resolution.

Can someone know why it's like that.

Comment: "and surprise, I got ..." ??? What did you get? We want to know XD

Comment: Sorry, I just add it to my message..... it's 288x480 :)